# Paginación de tabla de registros

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, datatables

Tengo una tabla html que estoy intentando hacerle una paginación, pero hasta ahora solo me salen unos números en cuadrado distorsionados y amontonados debajo de al menos 10 registros. He modificado la variable var registrosPorPagina para cantidad de registros por pagina pero no cumple la instrucción. En el archivo index.js esta la carga de registros desde Excel hacia una tabla, en el archivo filtropag.js tengo el filtrado por columna y la paginación, el filtrado si cumple esta cumpliendo su función pero la paginación no

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
html
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h2 class="text-center mt-4 mb-4">Tasa de Servicio</h2>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">Seleccione archivo Excel</div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <input type="file" id="excel_file" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="datos"></div>

    <div class="app">
        <input type="text" id="searchInput" placeholder="Filtrar por Nombre..." />
        <input type="text" id="searchInput1" placeholder="Filtrar por Cliente..." />
        <input type="text" id="searchInput2" placeholder="Filtrar por Descripcion..." />
        <input type="text" id="searchInput3" placeholder="Filtrar por Estatus..." />
        <input type="text" id="searchInput4" placeholder="Filtrar por Hobby..." />

        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr id="cabecera_table">
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="names">
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="pagination"></div>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/xlsx@0.15.1/dist/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="filtropag.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
const excel_file = document.getElementById('excel_file');

excel_file.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    if (!['application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', 'application/vnd.ms-excel'].includes(event.target.files[0].type)) {
        document.getElementById('excel_data').innerHTML = '<div class="alert alert-danger">Only .xlsx or .xls file format are allowed</div>';
        excel_file.value = '';
        return false;
    }

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(event.target.files[0]);

    reader.onload = function (event) {
        var data = new Uint8Array(reader.result);
        var work_book = XLSX.read(data, { type: 'array' });
        var sheet_name = work_book.SheetNames;
        var sheet_data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(work_book.Sheets[sheet_name[0]], { header: 1 });

        let cabecera = document.querySelector('#cabecera_table');
        cabecera.innerHTML = '';
        for (let item of sheet_data.shift()) {
            cabecera.innerHTML += `<th>${item}</th>`;
        }

        let names = document.querySelector('#names');
        names.innerHTML = sheet_data
            .map(fila =>
                `<tr>
                    ${fila.map(celda => `<td>${celda}</td>`).join('')}
                 </tr>`)
            .join('');
        //mostrarRegistros();
        actualizarPaginacion();
    }
});
```

filtropag.js //filtro y paginacion.

```
// Búsqueda inteligente y paginación
function filterColumn(columnIndex, inputId) {
  let value = document.getElementById(inputId).value.toUpperCase();
  let names = document.getElementById("names");
  let rows = names.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      let column = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[columnIndex];
      let language = column.textContent;
      rows[i].style.display =
          language.toUpperCase().indexOf(value) > -1 ? "" : "none";
  }
  mostrarRegistros(); // Agregamos esta línea para mostrar los registros filtrados
  actualizarPaginacion(); // Agregamos esta línea para actualizar la paginación después del filtrado

}

document.getElementById("searchInput").addEventListener("keyup", function () {
  filterColumn(0, "searchInput");
});

document.getElementById("searchInput1").addEventListener("keyup", function () {
  filterColumn(1, "searchInput1");
});

document.getElementById("searchInput2").addEventListener("keyup", function () {
  filterColumn(2, "searchInput2");
});

document.getElementById("searchInput3").addEventListener("keyup", function () {
  filterColumn(3, "searchInput3");
});

document.getElementById("searchInput4").addEventListener("keyup", function () {
  filterColumn(4, "searchInput4");
});

// Paginacion
var registrosPorPagina = 10; // Cambia el número de registros por página según tus necesidades
var paginaActual = 1;

function mostrarRegistros() {
  var nombres = document.getElementById("names");
  var filas = nombres.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  var inicio = (paginaActual - 1) * registrosPorPagina;
  var fin = inicio + registrosPorPagina;

  for (var i = 0; i < filas.length; i++) {
      filas[i].style.display = i >= inicio && i < fin ? "" : "none";
  }
}

function actualizarPaginacion() {
  var nombres = document.getElementById("names");
  var filas = nombres.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  var totalPaginas = Math.ceil(filas.length / registrosPorPagina);

  var paginacion = document.getElementById("pagination");
  paginacion.innerHTML = "";

  for (var i = 1; i <= totalPaginas; i++) {
      var boton = document.createElement("button");
      boton.innerText = i;
      boton.addEventListener("click", function () {
          paginaActual = parseInt(this.innerText);
          mostrarRegistros();
          actualizarPaginacion();
      });

      if (i === paginaActual) {
          boton.classList.add("active");
      }

      paginacion.appendChild(boton);
  }
  
  mostrarRegistros();
}

paginaActual = 1;
```

Comment: Estimado, lamentablemente tu preguntas y preguntas, pero nunca aceptas ninguna respuesta. Yo por lo menos paso de seguir respondiéndote

Comment: Hola, no se donde hacer clik para aceptar o no

Comment: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/301324

Answer (score 0):

ya logre corregir el principal problema, ahora corregí a que solo se muestren como 7 botones de paginación, unos puntos suspensivos para ocultar el resto de botones y las palabras "Anterior" (al inicio de los botones) y "Siguiente" (al final de los botones). Ahora lo que me falta y aun no puedo resolverlo es que esos botones de paginación siempre se ubiquen dos filas después del ultimo registro de la tabla, y el otro problema es que al inicio cuando carga la tabla se despliega toda la información encima de los botones de paginación, lo correcto seria que la carga de la pagina solo sea por 10 registros.

filtropag.js

```
// Búsqueda inteligente y paginación
function filterColumn(columnIndex, inputId) {
  let value = document.getElementById(inputId).value.toUpperCase();
  let names = document.getElementById("names");
  let rows = names.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  let visibleRows = 0; // Variable para contar los registros visibles

  for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    let column = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[columnIndex];
    let language = column.textContent;
    let isVisible = language.toUpperCase().indexOf(value) > -1;

    rows[i].style.display = isVisible ? "" : "none";

    if (isVisible) {
      visibleRows++;
      if (visibleRows > registrosPorPagina) {
        rows[i].style.display = "none"; // Ocultar los registros adicionales que superen el límite de registros por página
      }
    }
  }

  mostrarRegistros(); // Agregamos esta línea para mostrar los registros filtrados
  actualizarPaginacion(); // Agregamos esta línea para actualizar la paginación después del filtrado
}

document.getElementById("searchInput").addEventListener("keyup", function () {
  filterColumn(0, "searchInput");
});

document.getElementById("searchInput1").addEventListener("keyup", function () {
  filterColumn(1, "searchInput1");
});

document.getElementById("searchInput2").addEventListener("keyup", function () {
  filterColumn(2, "searchInput2");
});

document.getElementById("searchInput3").addEventListener("keyup", function () {
  filterColumn(3, "searchInput3");
});

document.getElementById("searchInput4").addEventListener("keyup", function () {
  filterColumn(4, "searchInput4");
});

var registrosPorPagina = 10; // Cambia el número de registros por página según tus necesidades
var paginaActual = 1;

function mostrarRegistros() {
  var nombres = document.getElementById("names");
  var filas = nombres.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  var inicio = (paginaActual - 1) * registrosPorPagina;
  var fin = inicio + registrosPorPagina;

  for (var i = 0; i < filas.length; i++) {
    filas[i].style.display = i >= inicio && i < fin ? "" : "none";
  }
}

function actualizarPaginacion() {
  var nombres = document.getElementById("names");
  var filas = nombres.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  var totalPaginas = Math.ceil(filas.length / registrosPorPagina);

  var paginacion = document.getElementById("pagination");
  paginacion.innerHTML = "";

  var maxPaginasMostradas = 6; // Máximo número de botones de paginación a mostrar
  var mitadMaxPaginas = Math.floor(maxPaginasMostradas / 2);
  var inicio = paginaActual - mitadMaxPaginas;
  var fin = paginaActual + mitadMaxPaginas;

  if (inicio <= 0) {
    inicio = 1;
    fin = Math.min(maxPaginasMostradas, totalPaginas);
  }

  if (fin > totalPaginas) {
    fin = totalPaginas;
    inicio = Math.max(totalPaginas - maxPaginasMostradas + 1, 1);
  }

  // Agregar botones de paginación
  for (var i = inicio; i <= fin; i++) {
    var boton = document.createElement("button");
    boton.innerText = i;
    boton.addEventListener("click", function () {
      paginaActual = parseInt(this.innerText);
      mostrarRegistros();
      actualizarPaginacion();
    });

    if (i === paginaActual) {
      boton.classList.add("active");
    }

    paginacion.appendChild(boton);
  }

  // Agregar puntos suspensivos si hay más páginas a la izquierda
  if (inicio > 1) {
    var puntosIzquierda = document.createElement("span");
    puntosIzquierda.innerText = "......";
    paginacion.insertBefore(puntosIzquierda, paginacion.firstChild);
  }

  // Agregar puntos suspensivos si hay más páginas a la derecha
  if (fin < totalPaginas) {
    var puntosDerecha = document.createElement("span");
    puntosDerecha.innerText = "......";
    paginacion.appendChild(puntosDerecha);
  }

  // Agregar botón "Anterior"
  if (paginaActual > 1) {
    var botonAnterior = document.createElement("button");
    botonAnterior.innerText = "Anterior";
    botonAnterior.addEventListener("click", function () {
      paginaActual--;
      mostrarRegistros();
      actualizarPaginacion();
    });
    paginacion.insertBefore(botonAnterior, paginacion.firstChild);
  }

  // Agregar botón "Siguiente"
  if (paginaActual < totalPaginas) {
    var botonSiguiente = document.createElement("button");
    botonSiguiente.innerText = "Siguiente";
    botonSiguiente.addEventListener("click", function () {
      paginaActual++;
      mostrarRegistros();
      actualizarPaginacion();
    });
    paginacion.appendChild(botonSiguiente);
  }
}

paginaActual = 1;
mostrarRegistros();
actualizarPaginacion();
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Saludos @JuanAlberto, recuerda que si quieres agregar más información a tu pregunta siempre puedes [editarla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/600567/edit), reservamos esta sección solo para respuestas completas que dan solución a la pregunta. ;)

Comment: Hola estimado Israel, como había solucionado casi al 80% pensé que era mejor actualizar el planteamiento de la pregunta. Solo quedaría pendiente una parte del problema para que me ayuden a solucionar. En todo caso gracias por la recomendación. Saludos